# Date of creation of a folder in windows in c

Tags: c, windows, time, directory, creation

I need the creation date of all the files in a directory,it's works for all the files but not for the folders.

```
int antiguedad(char * nombre){

ZeroMemory(&fileinfo, sizeof(BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION));
// obtain a handle to the file, in this case the file
// must be in the same directory as your application
HANDLE myfile = NULL;
//char * nombre = "nuevooo.txt";
myfile = CreateFileA(nombre,0x00,0x00,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);

// if we managed to obtain the desired handle
if(myfile!=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    //try to fill the structure with info regarding the file
    if(GetFileInformationByHandle(myfile, &fileinfo))
    {
       SYSTEMTIME systemTime;
       FileTimeToSystemTime(&fileinfo.ftCreationTime, &systemTime);
       printf("El archivo tiene %i dias \n", diferenciaEndias(systemTime.wDay,systemTime.wMonth, systemTime.wYear));
    }
    CloseHandle(myfile);
}
else {

    printf("IT A FOLDER \n");
}
return 0;

}
```

I think that a need a specific code for the folders, but i don't find anything

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL (it actually means the *absence* of all other attributes, including read-only/archive/system/hidden, etc, so it may not match what you expect - though it can be ignored depending on the CreateFile intent).

To obtain valid handles for folders, include FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS.